# Difference between unlogged and logged Cassandra batches in negative cases

Tags: cassandra

I understand the basic difference between LOGGED and UNLOGGED batches in Cassandra in terms of atomicity. Essentially, LOGGED batches are atomic while UNLOGGED are not. This means that all statements in a LOGGED batch get executed (or not executed) all together.

In the case of an UNLOGGED batch, if something goes wrong during the write operation of a composing statement, I know that the already executed statements are NOT rolledback, but does Cassandra notify the failure of the whole batch to the driver ?

Comment: Still learning a lot myself about Cassandra, but saw that deprecating unlogged batch is being debated:
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8303
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9283
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9282

Comment: write a mix of LWT (conditional) statements that are known to pass/fail and verify that?

Answer (score 7):

So logged batches use a log to record the batch operation and then execute it, removing it from the log when it is successful. Unlogged is still a batch operation but without the overhead of the log. In small amounts logged are ok but as you scale up this batch log could grow and become a problem point. The Datastax docs actually cover batching and some examples:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html

Example of [good batches](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html)

Example of [bad batches](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html)

Generally speaking batches have their use but I have seen them cause performance problems when overused because of the penalty you pay for grouping them up on a coordinator node. I often point folks to this [well known blog](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/) that outlines some useful info on batches too

Answer (score 0):

unlogged batches or batches itself gives good performance when batches are created to have all records pointing to one partition and for LOAD it can be presorted as per cluster key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).